Why should C++ uint8_t data not be printable?
On this github C++ related page the writer said

Note that the value_type of those two containers is uint8_t which is not a printable character, make sure to cast it to int before you print.

Why should this be so?
For numbers < 128 decimal the sign bit will be zero.
In an ASCII based system an eg "A" should be stored as decimal 65 = binary 0100 0001 for both signed and unsigned 8 bit integer types.
(Or in default 16 bit signed int as 0000 0000 0100 0001.)
Why should unint8_t need casting to int to print?
Note:  For characters with values above 127 decimal, casting to int will ensure that the 8th bit is not confused with the sign bit, but for either 7 or 8 bit ASCII stored in Uint8_t type, for me this does not seem to be an issue.

You are assuming that a byte is 8 bits. That is not necessarily true.

@PhilipKendall Thanks. I'm aware of the "what is a byte"  quagmire, having started with 8 bit machine language (not assembler :-) ) coding on then 'leading edge' 8 bit microprocessors 50+ years ago. I tried to cover that with my comments re ASCII, 7 bits and 8 bit integer types amd 0000000001100110 note, BUT could have been even more specific.

The 3 answers so far are very useful and address the what (which is what I really wanted) but somewhat (only) not the why. Approximating the sum of 3 answers they say that uint8_t is effectively char and not int, even though it is (often) recommended to use uintN8_t rather than int  to avoid implementation specific traps. About what I've come to expect of C++ so far :-).

@PhilipKendall ... and, thanks for that useful link.

If std::uint8_t is defined, then it is necessarily true that a byte is 8 bits. If a byte is not 8 bits, then std::uint8_t cannot exist.

'A' is 65, not 66.

The writer also frequents StackOverflow. Maybe you can ask them directly.

To add to the other answers with some more background about why this is an issue:
In C++, char, signed char, and unsigned char are three distinct types. char may be signed or unsigned, but that’s mostly irrelevant; char is not the same as either signed char or unsigned char. char is supposed to be used for character data (whatever that may mean; it gets complicated). signed char and unsigned char are supposed to be byte-sized integers, signed and unsigned respectively. (And std::byte is supposed to mean an actual byte just as a bag-of-bits, rather than a (integer) number.) Yes, it’s all numbers under the hood, but numbers mean different things in computing.
As noted in the other answers, some character values are not printable. So some values of char are not printable. However since signed char and unsigned char are supposed to represent numeric values, there should be no values of signed char or unsigned char that are unprintable.
However…
The fixed-width integer types in C++ are defined to be type aliases (“typedefs”)… not actual types. That means that std::int8_t is just an alias for some other type. And what type would it be an alias for? Well, the best choice on most platforms—often the only practical choice—is signed char.
Similarly, the best choice for the underlying type of std::uint8_t is unsigned char.
Now, unfortunately, IOStreams was specified to treat signed char and unsigned char just like char. In my opinion, this was a mistake. The upshot of that is that doing std::cout << std::int8_t{65} is exactly the same as doing std::cout << char{65}… which—even though std::int8_t is supposed to be a number, and should print 65—will probably print A on an ASCII or UTF-8 system.
(And it gets even worse, because std::int8_t doesn’t have to be aliased to signed char. It could be aliased to some other, platform-specific type. And that type could be treated as a number when using IOStreams. So you don’t even know whether std::cout << std::int8_t{??} will print a character or a number on other platforms. It’s a mess, which is why I say treating signed char and unsigned char the same as char when doing output was a mistake.)
This has been fixed in the modern formatting library. std::int8_t is still (probably) signed char, but the modern formatting library is smart enough to realize that signed char and unsigned char are not char, and it treats them appropriately as numbers. See for yourself.
One last thing: while it is not technically wrong to cast std::int8_t to int (and std::uint8_t to unsigned int), it’s a little verbose and unnecessary. It’s much simpler to just use the + prefix:
std::cout << std::int8_t{65};   // prints a character (probably 'A')
std::cout << +std::int8_t{65};  // always prints a number (65)

All the + is doing there is promoting the signed char (which std::int8_t really is) to int, which then prints normally as a number.
Doing it this way is optional for std::int8_t or signed char, because manually casting to int is always correct for those types. But if you ever want to print the numeric value of a char, using the + is the only correct way to do it. That is because you don’t know if char is signed or not, so you don’t know whether it is correct to cast it to a signed char or unsigned char. The + always does the right thing.

Is it a mistake? Char c = ‘!’, std::cout << c should print sn exclamation mark. Except when it shouldn’t :-(

@gnasher729 Sure. But we're talking about auto const c = std::uint8_t{33}; std::cout << c;.

You should be able to cast uint8_t to int just as correctly as to unsigned int, right?  And in fact that should be what + is doing.

"That means that std::int8_t is just an alias for some other type".  Can you provide a C++ standard reference for this claim ? char is not even guaranteed to be 8 bits as far as I remember, whereat uint8_t is.  Also, can you provide evidence about char being for character data and signed/unsigned char with a numeric meaning?  Considering that even c++ strings are only by default made of char and can be made of any types, I wonder whether standard maker ever had such a subjective differentiation in mind and am now very curious

The "+" conversion trick is cute and clever, and I've not seen it in my 35 years of C/C++ programming that I recall.  However, the "verbosity" of a cast is good, to spell out exactly what you're doing.  Software is write-once-read-many (WORM) and the key metric I'd normally judge code by is readability, not writability.

@SwissFrank - I've seen it in the wild, and even used it myself.  But it was hard to get past the code reviewers and now I wouldn't try: Your "verbosity"/readability point is a good one, and also for me the major guideline controlling my design+coding.

@MarkRansom Yes, since the minimum range for int is −32 768–32 767, it will always be true that all values of std::uint8_t can fit, so casting to int will always be fine. And since int is the first choice for implicit promotion, that’s what you’ll get. This won’t always be true for unsigned char, but whenever std::uint8_t exists, it will be.

@Christophe “Can you provide a C++ standard reference for this claim ?” Is the definition of std::int8_t not clear enough? In any case, it must be true, logically. A platform specifier can’t dictate what the types in std are, and a standard library writer can’t invent new fundamental types out of whole cloth. So the only possible way it can work is if the fixed-width types are type aliases. “char is not even guaranteed to be 8 bits as far as I remember, whereat uint8_t is.” Yes, but std::uint8_t is optional, and can exist if and only if char is 8 bits.

@Christophe “Also, can you provide evidence about char being for character data and signed/unsigned char with a numeric meaning?” What evidence do you want that a simple search won’t provide? If you are hoping for a standard stipulation, that’s not how the standard works. It doesn’t tell you what the fundamental types are “for”; that’s for you to decide. You could put fixed-point fractional values in an int if you want. It does say signed char and unsigned char are “integer types” and char is a “character type”… but that’s all.

@SwissFrank The trick is widely known (it’s the first answer here and here, and the second after an explicit cast to the correctly (un)signed type here and here, and it’s in the standard committee’s FAQ). It is the only correct way (without meta-programming) to get the numeric value of a char. An explicit cast to (unsigned) int would be non-portable.

@SwissFrank The verbosity of a cast is only good to highlight that you intend a cast… but that’s not the case here. You could cast std::uint8_t to int, to long, to unsigned… doesn’t matter, and you don’t care, because the cast is not the point. What you mean is “I want this to be a number”, and + more directly expresses that intent. c + 0 works, too. The mechanism by which it works (promotion/casting) is irrelevant, so the verbosity of a cast is actually misleading here. (Perhaps better would be a function as_number(), though the precise return type is irrelevant.)

It took me several readings, and I'm still not sure I follow the last paragraph.  Did you mean to write "you don’t know whether it is correct to cast it to a signed int or unsigned int" (as opposed to signed char / unsigned char)?  Because it is possible, albeit uncommon, that (signed) int cannot accommodate all values of type char when the latter is an unsigned type.

THank you for your feedback. No the definition of std::int8_t is not enough.  The standard shows that it CAN be an alias, but this alias is optional, leaving room for a build in type. See also my comment and reference to Bart's answer.

On the second point, I am still looking for any authoritative evidence of what seems to be a personal interpretation.  Indeed, char, signed char and unsigned char are 3 different types but according to C++ standard, they all belong to the "standard [signed/unsigned] integer types".  I'm double curious, because starting from K&R 40 years ago, going through the first release of C++, through all Bjarne's book including "design & evolution of C++", and most leading C++ authors, I did not yet find any such claim.  I'm eager to learn, please show me.

@Christophe I don't think there is any formal evidence for indi's categorical distinction between "computational" character types and "representational" char. The 2020 standard says "The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are
collectively called ordinary character types" in 6.8.2/7, and "Types bool, char, wchar_t, char8_t, char16_t, char32_t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are
collectively called integral types" in .../11, i.e., all character types are created equal except for the sign.

@Christophe That said, the only material reason one would want to be sure about the sign is that the value is used in computations. But hat's just a heuristic, though apparently strong enough to specify print's behavior.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica thank you.  This is indeed confirms my understanding and the 2023 standard did not change much in this regard.

@JohnBollinger “Did you mean to write "you don’t know whether it is correct to cast it to a signed int or unsigned int" (as opposed to signed char / unsigned char)?” No, I meant what I wrote. Because char can be signed or unsigned, you don’t know if it is generally safe to cast to either signed char or unsigned char. That is also true for casting to int or unsigned int, but I was making a point about the signedness problem, not casting to another type.

@Christophe “The standard shows that it CAN be an alias, but this alias is optional, leaving room for a build in type.” That is not what the standard shows at all. The standard defines it as an alias, and says its existence is optional… not the fact that it is an alias. That is explained quite clearly a paragraph or so later: “… if an implementation defines integer types with the corresponding width and no padding bits, it defines the corresponding typedef-names.” In plain English: if an appropriate built-in type exists, an alias will be defined.

@Christophe I still don’t know what evidence you were expecting. As I said, the standard does not dictate what any type is for; it just specifies properties. You want to use char for floating point data? Go for it. (It’s been done. See G.711.) Authors, trainers, and other experts study the type’s standardized properties, then recommend “this is what this type is best used for”. In this case, the recommendation that char is for character data only and signed char and unsigned char is for numeric data is pretty universal. 1/2

You mentioned Bjarne Stroustrup; well, he also says to only use char for character data in “The C++ Programming Language” (§6.2.3.1 in the current edition). Widely used C++ coding standards like MISRA (5-0-11 and 5-0-12) and CERT (INT07-C and STR00-C) say the same. None of these are “authoritative” unless you want them to be (or your employer/project makes them so). However, given the universality of the recommendation, it seems a stretch to call it “personal interpretation”. But hey, if you want to say my personal interpretation is influencing NASA, by all means. 2/2

Ok, @indi, then I guess you threw me by comparing that with a cast to int, especially since the cast to int will in fact do the job just fine for char on the vast majority of systems, and the unary + will anyway effect a promotion to int (probably) or unsigned int (maybe on a few weird systems).  I don't see why you'd want the signed char or unsigned char cast in the first place, and it doesn't seem analogous to the case for std::uint8_t. Anyway, however techically correct it may be, that paragraph didn't work for me.  Do with that what you want.


Why should unint8_t need casting to int to print?

So that cout will treat it as an int, not a char. See uint8-t cant be printed with cout.
You've focused on the signed bit, which maps to the reserved bit in ASCII, and ignored that some lower ASCII values map to "unprintable" control characters.


ASCII code - fastbitlab.com

That first column is all "unprintable" control characters.
Unprintable because rather than representing symbols to print, these values are attempts to control a terminal. cout may or may not be pointing at a terminal. Terminals will ding when you send them a bell. Printers wont.*
So it's not truly that you can't print this way, it's that you'd better be sure what you mean.
This line:


Note that the value_type of those two containers is uint8_t which is not a printable character, make sure to cast it to int before you print.


Is a little deceptive. It's not that the type is or isn't a printable character. It's that cout may surprise you by treating a type with int in its name as a char.
This line (which was next)
std::cout << static_cast<int>(v.front()) << "\n";
doesn't change the values. It just changes how they're interpreted and represented.

If you're wondering why I keep putting "unprintable" in scare quotes it's because that unprintable status is entirely context dependent. For example, in Notepad++ you can turn on Show All Characters and instead of hiding these unprintable characters it will print them (even null) on the screen using special symbols.

This does nothing to change the value of the data. It's a choice of how to present it.

  * It can be argued that some printers will ding when you send them a bell. I argue the more a printer does terminal things the less it's a printer and the more it's a terminal.

"Terminals will ding when you send them a bell. Printers wont." -- Some 80's/90's dot-matrix printers (Epson FX-80, iirc) would absolutely ding when you sent them a BEL character.

@RogerLipscombe better now?

The fact that a printer beeps doesn't mean it's a terminal.  On Epson-compatible printers, control-G had two effects: (1) It forced the printer to output any data received thus far, and (2) after that output was complete, it triggered the printer to momentary activate a beeper that would be used for alarms such as "out of paper".  If the printer had just output a long line in the left-to-right direction and received a small amount of text before a BEL, it would output any text received before the BEL--likely with a right-to-left stroke, and then output anything received after that...

...which was part of the same line using a left-to-right stroke.  I don't think any code was designed around that behavior of BEL (other control codes like backspace worked similarly) but I think Epson-compatible printers would generally behave similarly.

Given the context of the page mentioned, which is about vectors of 2 and 4-bit values, I can only guess that with printing they mean sending the value to an output stream (like std::cout) and getting the decimal representation of the number back.
This does not work with the type uint8_t, because that is an alias for unsigned char and the output streams interpret the bit pattern of unsigned char as representing a character instead of representing a number.
This means that if you use unsigned char or uint8_t to store numbers and you pass them without conversion to an output stream with the expectation to see numbers printed, you are in for a rude awakening. That is what the page tries to warn you about.

Is uint8_t always an alias for unsigned char, or is this an implementation dependent claim ? (the C++ standard does not specify that char is 8 bits as far as I know, whereas the 8 bits are guaranteed for uint8_t)

@Christophe, I haven't checked the C++ standard recently, but to my knowledge, char must be the smallest type and is the only one that can be as small as 8 bits. Thus, if the platform doesn't support 8-bit char, it also cannot support uint8_t/int8_t.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/15039190/3723423 - the "optional" are still in c++23 so I understand they could still be build in.

If c is an unsigned char with a value of ‘A’ then printing c to std::cout prints the letter ‘A’. Printing c cast to int prints “65”.
uint8_t has 256 different values. Printing each of them cast to int will print something from “0” to “255”. Trying to print each as a character will try to print many unprintable characters. Printable characters print a singe character. Printing unprintable characters can print anything.  Usually 32 to 126 are printable. In Windows more characters from 160 to 255 and possibly many but not all from 128 to 159 may be printable.
